# Kotlin: Fragment not attached, Unable to instantiate fragment calling fragment const caused exception

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to pass a childFragmentManager from a fragment to an adapter. The current fragment is called from a different fragment and not activity.

the fragment class has a val

```
class DisplaySchoolFrag : BaseFragment<binding, DisplaySchoolViewModel>{
...

private val adapter = DisplaySchoolAdapter(childFragmentManager)
```

In the adapter I just have the const declaration for childFrag no other usage for now.

```
class DisplaySchoolAdapter(childFrag: FragmentManager) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

I need the childFragmentManager inside the adapter, because inside the adapter class theres a button which leads to bottomsheet fragment.

```
FragmentHostCallback<?> mhost
getChildFrar(){
if (this.mHost == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " has not been attached yet.");
```

and this line is causing the Fragment not attached, Unable to instantiate fragment calling fragment const caused exception

i tried this

```
lateinit var childFrag : FragmentManager


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
         childFrag = childFragmentManager
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }
```

and passing the childFrag into the DisplaySchoolAdapter(childFrag) declaration still getting the error.

Comment: Can you show more of your adapter class? All you shared is some random bits of uncompilable code so it's hard to tell what's wrong with it. Quick and dirty fix would be to make the adapter property lazy, but I think it would be better to get to the bottom of the issue (make your adapter more robust). `private val adapter: DisplaySchoolAdapter by lazy { DisplaySchoolAdapter(childFragmentManager) }`

Comment: My two cents is that you should pass in a lambda into your adapter and override the `onClick` property and invoke the lambda. Then in your fragment you can get the childFragmentManager and go wherever it is you need to go

Comment: @Rafa, yes, it would be much better separation of concerns to use a listener approach. Let the Fragment decide what a button click should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in a callback in to `DisplaySchoolAdapter` and override the individual item's `setOnClickListener` listener and invoke the callback.

```
class DisplaySchoolAdapter(lambdaToBeInvoked: () -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeViewHolder>() {

   ... set up your adapter

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
     val item = items[position]
     holder.bind(item)
     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { lambdaToBeInvoked() }
   }
}
```

You can fill in the implementation details in the rest of your adapter, but the `onBindViewHolder` is where you would invoke the callback. If you need to pass any parameters into there, then feel free to add those in your implementation.

Then in your fragment when you instantiate your adapter you would pass in what you want your childFragment to do.

```
class YourFragment: FragmentActivity() {
 
    override onCreate() {
         
         val adapter = DisplaySchoolAdapter {
              // have your childFragment navigate to somewhere
         }

         recyclerView.adapter = adapter
         recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager()
    }

}
```